# Visual Studio Professional has started auto-saving on tab switch. How do I turn it off?

Tags: visual-studio

In VS Pro, when I make a change to a file and then switch tabs to another file, the first file is saved.  How do I disable this behavior and go back to saving only as I command? Is this a new feature in Visual Studio Pro or is there some extension doing this that I cannot find?

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed in VS that are doing this for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior was caused for me by Mads Kristensen's Tweaks extension.  Strangely, such did not show up in an options search, so I have [filed an issue for Mads](https://github.com/madskristensen/Tweakster/issues/85).

To fix, go to Tools -> Options -> Tweaks and find the "Auto save" option there.